# EF Core 5 check if all ids from filter exists in related entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two models:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Skill> { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And I have filter with list of skill ids, that employee should contain:

```
public class Filter
{
    public IList<int> SkillIds { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write query to get all employees, that have all skills from filter.

I tried:

```
query.Where(e => filter.SkillIds.All(id => e.Skills.Any(skill => skill.Id == id)));
```

And:

```
query = query.Where(e => e.Skills
                .Select(x => x.Id)
                .Intersect(filter.SkillIds)
                .Count() == filter.SkillIds.Count);
```

But as a result I get exception says that query could not be translated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works:

```
foreach (int skillId in filter.SkillIds)
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.Skills.Any(skill => skill.Id == skillId));
}
```

I am not sure about it's perfomance, but works pretty fast with small amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be a difficult, if not impossible task, to run a query like this on the sql server side.
This is because to make this work on the SQL side, you would be grouping each set of employee skills into a single row which would need to have a new column for every skill listed in the `skills` table.
SQL server wasn't really made to handle grouping with an unknown set of columns passed into a query. Although this kind of query is technically possible, it's probably not very easy to do through a model binding framework like ef core.

It would be easier to do this on the .net side using something like:

```
var employees = _context.Employees.Include(x=>x.Skill).ToList();
var filter = someFilter;
var result = employees.Where(emp => filter.All(skillID=> emp.skills.Any(skill=>skill.ID == skillID))).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added answer with solution I found

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this issue several times now, this is the query I've come up with that I found works best and does not result in an exception.

```
query.Where(e => e.Skills.Where(s => filter.SkillIds.Contains(s.Id)).Count() == filter.SkillIds.Count);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33558600)